Jenkins builds the state preservation problem
I want to understand how Jenkins saves the current build status during the build process, because I found that sometimes my build will trigger ：
java.io.NotSerializableException: java.util.HashMap$Node
during the data transfer process.
I want to understand the mechanism of Jenkins. It is best to have official documentation.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
